# Lines Breaks and \cref

Tags: cross-referencing, line-breaking, margins, cleveref

I have a problem with `\cref` not breaking lines, see the figure below:

[image: Parts of the equation reference comes outside the margin, and should rather be on the next row]

*Parts of the equation reference comes outside the margin, and should rather be on the next row*

Anyone with suggestions how to make this happen?

Thank you in advance!

/Lars

Comment: Is that really a `\cref`? It looks like an ordinary `\ref` or `\eqref` to me.

Comment: If you haven't done so yet include `\usepackage{microtype}` to your preamble. It might solve this. And if it doesn't it will improve the typography of your document anyway.

Comment: There is always the option to force breaking manually with `\linebreak`